# C# Linked List enqueue and dequeue method syntax

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

I have a project that requires us to use linked list stacks(`NodeStack`) and queues(`NodeQueue`). I have this sample code to work with:

```
class Node
{
    object value;
    Node next;

    public void setValue(object o)
    {
        value = o;
    }

    public object getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setNext(Node o)
    {
        next = o;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
}

class NodeStack
{
    Node top;
    int count;

    public void Push(object o)
    {
        Node newTop = new Node();
        newTop.setValue(o);
        newTop.setNext(top);

        top = newTop;
        count = count + 1;
    }

    public object Pop()
    {
        object value = top.getValue();
        top = top.getNext();
        return value;
    }

    public object Peek()
    {
        return top.getValue();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        top = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

From this code I should be able to derive the `NodeStack` to a `NodeQueue`but I have trouble understanding the syntax for the `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` methods. When I run a simple enqueue and dequeue program I get a Null reference exception on the 1st line of the dequeue method. Really appreciate the help.

Code I have so far:

```
class NodeQueue
{
    Node tail;
    Node head;
    int count;

    public void Enqueue(object o)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            Node newHead = new Node();
            newHead.setValue(o);
            head = tail = newHead;
            newHead.setNext(tail);
        }
        else
        {
            Node newTail = new Node();
            newTail.setValue(o);
            newTail.setNext(tail);
            tail = newTail;
        }
        count++;
    }

    public object Dequeue()
    {
        object value = head.getValue();
        head = head.getNext();
        return value;

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The problem with the NullException has been handled but now I have a problem with dequeue. I am using this program to test the queue

```
NodeQueue nq = new NodeQueue();
        nq.Enqueue(1);
        nq.Enqueue(2);
        nq.Enqueue(3);
        nq.Enqueue(4);
        nq.Enqueue(5);

        Console.WriteLine(nq.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(nq.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(nq.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(nq.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine(nq.Dequeue());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The expected output would be 1..5. The output that happens though is that 1 keeps getting printed.

Comment: This is homework. So I'll just nudge you a little. What if the queue was empty to begin with? What do you think your code will do when you try to dequeue?

Comment: @sinewaver if it's empty then I suppose it would find `value` to be null and return a null exception?

Comment: In your enqueue method, you never set the `tail` (or `head`) to anything.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `Dequeue` decrement the `count`?

Comment: @RufusL Oh I see, thanks. I get what sinewaver was trying to say now. Although there's a new problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Enqueue`method is not correct thats why your are getting exception in 'Dequeue`

Also in `Dequeue` you should reduce count by one.

In your `Enqueue` `head` is not set.

```
class NodeQueue
{
    Node tail;
    Node head;
    int count;

    public void Enqueue(object o)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            Node newHead = new Node();
            newHead.setValue(o);
            head = tail = newHead;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newTail = new Node();
            newTail.setValue(o);
            tail.setNext(newTail);
            tail = newTail;
        }
        count++;
    }

    public object Dequeue()
    {
        if (null != head)
        {
            object value = head.getValue();
            head = head.getNext();
            count--;
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a new problem though. When I run the program it would only dequeue the first one that I enqueue repeatedly

Comment: yes... it will dequeue first one.. because Queue is FIFO. and yes there is an update in dequeue method. I will update my answer.

Comment: please check...
and can you explain your question a bit more here "When I run the program it would only dequeue the first one that I enqueue repeatedly"

Comment: I enqueue the numbers 1 to 5. So naturally when I dequeue it should print 1 2 3 4 5. What happens is it prints 1 1 1 1 1. I edited the question above to add the code I use to check.

Comment: Can you use the class 'NodeQueue` which i created. it is working fine. i ran it in my system.

Comment: Great. If it worked for you. Please mark it as Accepted answer and upvote. :)